# Distribution and probability of any given number when generated randomly in different chunk sizes

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random, neural-networks

Consider i generate a 100000 numbers of 9 digit number in two ways

1. Generate it as first a 5 digit random number and then a 4 digit number and concatenate both
2. Generate it as three, three digit random number and concatenate them to form the 9 digit number
   The question is
   Q1.  Will the distribution of the 100000 random numbers generated from the two methods listed above be different.  If so how to mathematically prove it
   Q1.  Will the probability of generating any given number be different across the two methods listed above. If so how to mathematically prove it.
   From my calculation it appears there is no difference, yet a neural network is able to distinguish between the two batches of numbers statistically.  So I am at a loss to explain what the difference is that the network is catching up on.

Comment: Not following.  If you concatenate a $5$ and a $4$ digit integer, in that order, then surely the sixth digit  (from the left, lead digit of the $4$ digit number) of the result can never be $0$, right?

Comment: Once you correct for the leading digit problem, then all these methods should end up being the same.  Each slot is equally likely to be any of the digits (again, leading zeroes being handled however you choose), and that's all that matters.

Comment: If you have accounted for leading zeroes, then it might be the way you generate random k-digit numbers has some statistical tendency which the neural net is able to detect.

Comment: With very few exceptions, random number generators produce only pseudo-random numbers. Perhaps a service like random.org could generate random seeds, and if you choose a new random seed before choosing each number, perhaps it will be sufficiently random for a neural network.

Comment: @lulu i prefix the numbers with zeros

Comment: What does that mean?  Each of your integers has a leading $0$?  But then of course the concatenation is forced to have $0's$ in certain places.

Comment: I generate number with chunks of fixed digits as i mentioned, if the generated number is not of that fixed chunk size i prefix it to zero to make it that chunk size